# Having problems drawing animations in monogame

Tags: c#, animation, sprite, monogame, sprite-sheet

I am trying to create a spaceship with multiple animations (idle, attack, damaged, etc)
But when I'm trying to change the animations I see the first frame of the current animation for a split second on the "old" position (where the animation was changed the last time)

Picture for explanation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BgNK.png

*The red rectangle is supposed to be a health bar.*

The class that runs my animations:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace Test
{
    class Animation
    {
        Texture2D spriteStrip;
        float scale;
        int elapsedTime;
        int frameTime;
        int frameCount;
        int currentFrame;
        Color color;
        // The area of the image strip we want to display
        Rectangle sourceRect = new Rectangle();    
        // The area where we want to display the image strip in the game
        Rectangle destinationRect = new Rectangle();
        public int FrameWidth;
        public int FrameHeight;
        public bool Active;
        public bool Looping;
        public Vector2 Position;    
        public void Initialize(Texture2D texture, Vector2 position, int frameWidth, int frameHeight, int frameCount, int frametime, Color color, float scale, bool looping)
        {
            this.color = color;
            this.FrameWidth = frameWidth;
            this.FrameHeight = frameHeight;
            this.frameCount = frameCount;
            this.frameTime = frametime;
            this.scale = scale;
            Looping = looping;
            Position = position;
            spriteStrip = texture;
            elapsedTime = 0;
            currentFrame = 0;

            Active = true;
        }
        public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (Active == false) return;

            elapsedTime += (int)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
            if (elapsedTime > frameTime)
            {
                currentFrame++;
                if (currentFrame == frameCount)
                {
                    currentFrame = 0;
                    if (Looping == false)
                        Active = false;
                }
                elapsedTime = 0;
            }
            sourceRect = new Rectangle(currentFrame * FrameWidth, 0, FrameWidth, FrameHeight);
            destinationRect = new Rectangle((int)Position.X - (int)(FrameWidth * scale) / 2, (int)Position.Y - (int)(FrameHeight * scale) / 2, (int)(FrameWidth * scale), (int)(FrameHeight * scale));
        }
        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            if (Active)
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(spriteStrip, destinationRect, sourceRect, color);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The reason that I wrote the whole code is because I don't know where the problem is.
In my Game1.cs class I have:

---

Global Variables:

```
Texture2D playerTexture;
Texture2D playerShootingTexure;
Animation playerAnimation = new Animation();
Animation ShootingAnimation = new Animation();
```

...

```
protected override void LoadContent()
{
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        playerTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Graphics/Player/PlayerShip");
        playerShootingTexure = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Graphics/Player/Player_Shooting");
        playerAnimation.Initialize(playerTexture, Vector2.Zero, playerTexture.Width / 5, playerTexture.Height, 5, 50, Color.Wheat, 1f, true);
        ShootingAnimation.Initialize(playerShootingTexure, Vector2.Zero, playerShootingTexure.Width / 5, playerShootingTexure.Height, 5, 50, Color.WhiteSmoke, 0.75f, true);
}
```

Where I change the animations:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        // Start drawing
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        if (Player_Attacking == false)
        {
            player.PlayerAnimation = playerAnimation;
        }
        else
        {
            player.PlayerAnimation = ShootingAnimation;
        }
        player.Draw(spriteBatch);
        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

Note: Player_Attacking is a boolean variable. When 'Space' is pressed, the value of the variable changes to TRUE, when 'Space' is released, value is FALSE

Please help!
Thanks in advance!
And sorry for huge wall of text

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear on the exact issue, so maybe you can help clarify if I'm not understanding.

But based on your picture, it seems when you press space to fire, the player animation should change to light up his gun with blue flames (or w/e it is :)) And it looks like it is doing that, but it's in the wrong position (above the health bar - I see the laser it is shooting is in the right location :))

But then it corrects itself once the shooting is done, as shown by the second picture (no more blue flames).

So this implies the Animation for the Player Shooting is using the wrong position.

Are you:

1. Updating your Player Shooting Animation's Position in your Player Update?
2. Calling your Player Shooting Animation's `Update` in your Player Update?

so you should have this somewhere in your Player `Update`

```
PlayerAnimation.Position = Position;
PlayerAnimation.Update(gameTime);
```

Also, try moving the check for which Player Animation to use in the `Update` of your Game1.cs:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    if (Player_Attacking == false)
    {
        player.PlayerAnimation = playerAnimation;
    }
    else
    {
        player.PlayerAnimation = ShootingAnimation;
    }
    player.Update(gameTime);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I did a different fix. I made the "spriteStrip" variable in the Animation class a public variable. And then instead of changing the animation of the player, I change the sprite sheet.

Comment: cool. Also, it's worth checking out cocos2d-xna. I make games in Monogame just like you and I ported my code over to use Monogame with cocos2d-xna. It makes stuff like this much easier to grasp. Look into TexturePacker, which lets you make sprite sheets for cocos2d-xna. Good luck!

Comment: What's the difference between monogame and cocos2d-xna? Do I have to change a lot of code?

Comment: cocos2d-xna and monogame are very similar (both are open source game frameworks), but can be combined to get the best of both worlds. Cocos also has Box2D support (a physics engine), but that's probably too far ahead for now. Cocos provides a pretty extensive API to cover many things like sprites, animations, layers, actions, and scenes. And you don't have to change much code. Just have your Player and screens inherit CCSprite and CCLayer respectively and look at tutorials to see what functionality you can achieve!